# CoreData saving/fetching many-to-many relationship

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I want to achieve simple stuff, but I just think i missed some point of how coreData functions. So I have made a createSession func, which job is to create a session, with some exercises to it. A exercise should be able to have a connection to multiple sessions and vice versa. So i made the following datamodel:
[image]

From here i went in an made the ExerciseMO and SessionMO:

```
class SessionMO: NSManagedObject {

@NSManaged var name: String?
@NSManaged var exercises: NSSet

}
```

and

```
class ExerciseMO: NSManagedObject {

@NSManaged var name: String
@NSManaged var mainMuscle: Int
@NSManaged var difficulty: Bool
@NSManaged var session: SessionMO

}
```

My save functions:

```
func createSession(name: String, exercisesConnect: [ExerciseMO]){

    var newExercises: NSSet = []

    guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else { return }
    let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

    for exercise in exercisesConnect {

        let newExercise = exercise as ExerciseMO
        let session = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Sessions", into: managedContext) as! SessionMO
        session.name = name
        newExercise.sessions?.adding(session)

        print("\(newExercise.name!) is saved under session named: \(session.name!)")
    }

    do {
        try! managedContext.save()
        print("Session '\(name)' is saved successfully.")
    }
}
```

and it works, or idk if it works. Because when i try to fetch the session, and get the exercises connected it always gives me 0 back.

My fetch function:

```
func findSession(name: String) {

    guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else { return }
    let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let sessionEntity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Sessions", in: managedContext)!

    let sessionFetch = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Sessions")
    sessionFetch.fetchLimit = 1
    sessionFetch.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name = %@", name)

    print("Here 1.")

    do {

        print("Here 2.")
        let sessions = try! managedContext.fetch(sessionFetch)
        print("Here 3.")
        for session in sessions as! [SessionMO] {
            print("Here 4.")
            print(session.name!)
            if let exercises = session.exercises {
                print("Here 5.")
                print(exercises.count)

            }
        }
    }
}
```

And example of the printout:

Save prints:

- Løb is saved under session named: Mandag
- Bænnkpres is saved under session named: Mandag
- Session 'Mandag' is saved successfully.

Fetch prints:

- Here 1.
- Here 2.
- Here 3.
- Here 4.
- Mandag
- Here 5.
- 0

So if anyone could point me in a way or anything helpfull it would be highly appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: The code is pretty ambiguous. Is the entity name `Sessions` or `SessionMO`? Why is `sessions` in code declared as (single) `session` in the model? In code most of the properties are optional, in the model they are not. And finally you are creating one session for each exercise. Is this intended?

Comment: Well Sessions is the reference to CoreData, SessionsMO stands for the managed object class. And sessions is just the load in variable, i should properly rename it to result. And session is just a SessionMO.

Comment: Ill properly followed to many different guide, but i dont find the internet so helpful on CoreData many-many relationships. Either it’s outdated or just to-many relationship.

Comment: The intention is i want one session which is saved on each exercise which the user chose. So When i fetch the session i get all the exercises.